# Angular2 apache rewriting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, angular, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm using Angular2 to build a web mobile application, when i build my project and run it on local, everything works perfectly but when i push it into our production system i have problem, i think it's about Apache Rewriting !

My url in local http://127.0.0.1/
My url un prod http://domain.tld/mobile/

When my application is on production, it doesn't load any link like css or js ... so my application doesn't work !

My .htaccess look like this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

So to resolve my issue i think i need to edit my htaccess but how can i say to it to use /mobile and / but if i put only /mobile my application will do not work on local..

So if you have any idea ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either try to change your local development to serve from a subfolder named `mobile` and place your project in there. You need to change your `base href` tag inside your `index.html` to:

```
<base href="/">
```

Another option could be to only change the base href inside the  `index.html` of your production build.

If you are using the `angular-cli`, it has an option to edit the `base href` during the build process:

```
ng build --base-href=mobile
```

Comment: Thanks ! Your solution resolve another issue what i have, but even i build my app like this, apache rewriting is not able to get my css and js ressources!

Comment: your `RewriteBase` is set to `/`, I guess it should be set to `/mobile`